# How can i get the parent of node text value in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectnodes

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I found the title named "Midnight Rain". Now i want to know who is his parent so that i can use the `<author>` text node. I tried something like:

```
  var xpath = "../*[local-name() != 'title']";
       xml.Load(xmlalltext);
       var xl1 = xml.SelectNodes(xpath);
       MessageBox.Show(xl1.Item(0).InnerText.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've already found the title node and you're looking for the parent node, you can just select the parent node of the current node.

```
var parentNode = titleNode.SelectSingleNode("..");
```

If you're looking for the author node:

```
var authorNode = titleNode.SelectSingleNode("../author");
```

Alternatively, you may look for preceding or following siblings:

```
var authorNode = titleNode.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::author") ?? titleNode.SelectSingleNode("preceding-sibling::author");
```

Edit:  To answer your comment, if you only have the string of the title, then you may use the following to get the author:

```
string xml = @"xml...";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string author = doc
    .Descendants("book")
    .Where(x => x.Element("title").Value == "Midnight Rain")
    .Select(x => x.Element("author").Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I have just the string "Midnight Rain", and i want to search for his author. I do understand the logic of your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

using XLinq

sample.xml(in below snipped) contains xml data

```
        XElement root = XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText("sample.xml"));

        var matchingBooks = root.Descendants().Where(i=>String.Equals(i.Value,"Midnight Rain")).Select(i=>i.Parent) ;
        var authors = matchingBooks.Elements("author");
```

Output  in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

```
 matchingBooks.Dump();

authors.Dump();

<book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
            an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
            of the world.</description>
        </book>
```

---

```
<author>Ralls, Kim</author>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath expession to get author node

```
"/catalog/book[title='Midnight Rain']/author"
```

or this to get parent node

```
"/catalog/book[title='Midnight Rain']"
```

eg.

```
 var result = xml.SelectNodes(string.Format("/catalog/book[title='{0}']/author", "Midnight Rain"))
```