# Get parent node from xml

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an xml message as shown below. When I am processing this xml I want to get all parent nodes of "TransactionID" node that contain TransactionID with value of TRN001. I am using C# to do this. How can this be done ?

TIA

```
<Parent xmlns="http://baqwas">
    <Child1>
        <Child1>
            <TransactionID>TRN001</TransactionID>
        </Child1>
        <Child1>
            <TransactionID>TRN002</TransactionID>
        </Child1>
    </Child1>
    <Child2>
        <Child2>
            <TransactionID>TRN001</TransactionID>
            <TransDetails>123</TransDetails>
        </Child2>
        <Child2>
            <TransactionID>TRN001</TransactionID>
            <TransDetails>456</TransDetails>
        </Child2>
        <Child2>
            <TransactionID>TRN001</TransactionID>
            <TransDetails>789</TransDetails>
        </Child2>
        <Child2>
            <TransactionID>TRN001</TransactionID>
            <TransDetails>101112</TransDetails>
        </Child2>
        <Child2>
            <TransactionID>TRN002</TransactionID>
            <TransDetails>ABC</TransDetails>
        </Child2>
        <Child2>
            <TransactionID>TRN002</TransactionID>
            <TransDetails>DEF</TransDetails>
        </Child2>
        <Child2>
            <TransactionID>TRN002</TransactionID>
            <TransDetails>GHI</TransDetails>
        </Child2>
    </Child2>
</Parent>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683054/xpath-to-select-element-based-on-childs-child-value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the parent of node text value in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580607/how-can-i-get-the-parent-of-node-text-value-in-c)

Comment: My question appears to be different from both the comments above. I am looking for "TransactionID" and it is in different parent nodes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Linq2Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml) and [XPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-query-linq-to-xml-using-xpath)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(yourxmlstring);
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://baqwas");

var elems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//ns:TransactionID[text()='TRN001']", mgr)
            .Select(x=>x.Parent)
            .ToList();
```

or

```
var elems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//*/ns:TransactionID[text()='TRN001']", mgr)
            .ToList();
```

or

```
XNamespace ns = "http://baqwas";
var elems = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "TransactionID")
            .Where(x => (string)x == "TRN001")
            .Select(x => x.Parent)
            .ToList();
```